# avoiding write conflicts while re-sorting a table

Tags: sql, database-design, transactions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a large table that I need to re-sort periodically.  I am partly basing this on a suggestion I was given to stay away from using cluster keys since I am inserting data ordered differently (by time) from how I need it clustered (by ID), and that can cause re-clustering to get a little out of control.

Since I am writing to the table on a hourly I am wary of causing problems with these two processes conflicting: If I CTAS to a newly sorted temp table and then swap the table name it seems like I am opening the door to have a write on the source table not make it to the temp table.

I figure I can trigger a flag when I am re-sorting that causes the ETL to pause writing, but that seems a bit hacky and maybe fragile.

I was considering leveraging locking and transactions, but this doesn't seem to be the right use case for this since I don't think I'd be locking the table I am copying from while I write to a new table. Any advice on how to approach this?

Comment: Why not partition by id?

Comment: Define "large" in record count and total size.  And what is special about the ID that you are sorting on?  Do users filter on the ID column?  Is it a unique key on the table?  Is it sequential (getting larger over time)?

Comment: Right now it's at 13B records, and 0.5T and does get larger over time. This is about 2months of data; I already have another table acting as an older shard with 86B rows.

Comment: @BradKagawa How unique is the ID that you are clustering on and is that was is used to filter when querying that table?

Comment: Yeah the ID is always in my where clause, which is why I would like to order by it or cluster by it.  It is not a unique ID for the table and can be present in the entire table were it sorted by time...  Best analogy I can think of is if I were tracking purchases of a specific product through a history of transaction records. The transactions come in chronologically but the product ID that I filter for is interspersed so I need to re-order or cluster... If this doesn't work well I may start sharding the tables but I don't love the idea of maintaining so many tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some reasons to avoid the automatic reclustering, but they're basically all the same reasons why you shouldn't set up a job to re-cluster frequently. You're making the database do all the same work, but without the built in management of it.

If your table is big enough that you are seeing performance issues with the clustering by time, and you know that the ID column is the main way that this table is filtered (in JOINs and WHERE clauses) then this is probably a good candidate for automatic clustering.

So I would recommend at least testing out a cluster key on the ID and then monitoring/comparing performance.

---

To give a brief answer to the question about resorting without conflicts as written:
I might recommend using a time column to re-sort records older than a given time (probably in a separate table). While it's sorting, you may get some new records. But you will be able to use that time column to marry up those new records with the, now sorted, older records.

Comment: I can try that, I have not seen a way to keep an eye on how much compute time is being attributed to the autoclustering, is this something that Snowflake breaks down in the billing anywhere?

Comment: Information on Viewing billing for automatic clustering is at the bottom of the page here: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/tables-auto-reclustering.html#viewing-automatic-clustering-billing

Answer (score 1):

I've asked some clarifying questions in the comments regarding the clustering that you are avoiding, but in regards to your sort, have you considered creating a nice 4XL warehouse and leveraging the INSERT OVERWRITE option back into itself?  It'd look something like:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE INTO table SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id;
```

Assuming that your table isn't hundreds of TB in size, this will complete rather quickly (inside an hour, I would guess), and any inserts into the table during that period will queue up and wait for it to finish.

Comment: This is a reasonable idea depending on detailed needs. Potential downsides: Because there is a truncate, this could put your table into a temporarily "invalid" state while records are being re-inserted where your table has some Old records, some new records, and a gap in between. New records could get inserted alongside the re-inserts in the same table and cause micropartitions to have wide ranges of ids, which would defeat the purpose here.

Comment: This isn't actually how that works.  There is no truncate.  In Snowflake, the INSERT OVERWRITE creates new micropartitions and when it is complete, creates the new metadata that points to those micropartitions.  The metadata is locked during this operation, so no other insert statements would execute.  They would queue up behind the commit of the INSERT OVERWRITE.

Comment: huh. the Snowflake docs say "Overwrite specifies to truncate the target table before inserting into the table, while retaining access control privileges on the table" https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/insert.html
I'll have to look at that closer I suppose.
Thanks.

Comment: My point was, you'll never see a TRUNCATE statement executed.  It all happens within the metadata update, and this is locked during the process.  So, there isn't a way for records to "sneak" into the table.

Comment: Ah. I suppose that makes sense. thank you for the clarifications.

Comment: The documentation isn't super clear on this; does that mean the table will be manually re-ordered every time I do an insert?

Comment: it will only do the reordering when this specific "insert overwrite" query is run. If you run a separate insert without the overwrite it will be inserted just like it is now with the ordering based on time.

Answer (score -1):

You might consider revoking INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE privileges on the original table within the same script or procedure that performs the CTAS creating the newly sorted copy of the table.  After a successful swap you can re-enable the privileges for the roles that are used to perform updates.

Comment: This would cause incoming queries to fail unhelpfully. AND it requires higher level permissions which are otherwise unnecessary. Locking the table serves a similar purpose and is simpler.